# ValueError: Could not broadcast input array from shape (x,y) into shape (x-1, y) for arrays with shape defined with the same variables

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

I am trying to save an array into a bigger one by excluding the margins of the destination one. It works most of the time, but sometimes the shape of the destination array seems to change without an obvious reason. I really don't understand where the error is coming from, as both shapes are defined with the same variables (Size_X and Size_Y).

```
Image_target_no_margins = cv2.resize((Result_cllRuntime['writeResult']['depthData']*-1), dsize=(Size_X,Size_Y))

# create an array full of 0 with the shape of the Image
Image_target = np.zeros((Size_Y_ini, Size_X_ini))
Image_target[Corner_index_Y:Corner_index_Y+Size_Y, Corner_index_X:Corner_index_X+Size_X] = Image_target_no_margins
```

The error I got, in this case, is "ValueError: Could not broadcast input array from shape (1500,1500) into shape (1499, 1500)"

I printed out a few variables:

Size_X = 1500

Size_Y = 1500

Size_X_ini = 1700

Size_Y_ini = 1600

Corner_index_X = 102

Corner_index_Y = 101

I just don't see how the shapes can be different, but maybe I am looking at this the wrong way. Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the numerical values in this line

```
Image_target[Corner_index_Y:Corner_index_Y+Size_Y, Corner_index_X:Corner_index_X+Size_X] = Image_target_no_margins
```

in this case would be

```
Image_target[101:1601, 102:1602] = Image_target_no_margins
```

and since `Image_target` has shape (1600, 1700),
`Image_target[101:1601, 102:1602]` will become `Image_target[101:1600, 102:1602]`, making its new shape (1499,1500) instead of 1500.

And the reason it was working most of the time is that `Corner_index_Y` was <= 100.
Now I just have to find where I went wrong with defining `Corner_index_Y`

Answer (score 0):

In numpy array first axis is Y and second is X. So the code should be:

```
Image_target = np.zeros((Size_Y_ini, Size_X_ini))
Image_target[Corner_index_Y:Corner_index_Y+Size_Y, Corner_index_X:Corner_index_X+Size_X] = Image_target_no_margins
```

Comment: It actually was like this in my code, and I had forgotten the reason and I thought it just was because it was a square that it worked. So I changed it for the question. Thanks for the clarification, I'll change it back in my question